# How to create a named range of cells based on value of another column in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following sheet of data

```
Channel Quarter Week value
a       1       1    5811
a       1       2     199
a       1       1    8111
a       2       2     881
a       2       1     124
b       2       2    1991
```

I need to update the value column based on the combination of Channel and Quarter columns (I have created a helper column which would serve as a key)

```
Helper Channel Quarter Week value
 a1      a       1       1    5811
 a1      a       1       2     199
 a1      a       1       1    8111
 a2      a       2       2     881
 a2      a       2       1     124
 b2      b       2       2    1991
```

From my VBA form, I have a created a dictionary with the names in these helper columns like

```
 cellDict = [a1:= 1000, 2:= 2000, b1:= 500 etc]
```

Now I want to update the value of 'value' column on the basis of this dictionary in such a way that the cells corresponding to a1 be updated with 1000/3 each (As the number of rows for a1 is 3) and similarly cells corresponding to a2 be updated with 1000/2 each.

The attempt was to create a named range for value column with separate helper names and then iterate over each named range and update the cell value by taking the total value and dividing it by count of that named range

So, my question is how do I create a named range with value column on the basis of helper column so that I have (Assuming value is column V)

```
Range("a1") = V1:V3
Range("a2") = V4:V5 etc..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this without named ranges in a lot easier way.

First of all, I assume the rows are sorted by your helper column!
Just find the first `a1` in the helper column eg. with [`find` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) and get its row number as `rowStart`.

Then use [`WorksheetFunction.CountIf` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheetfunction-countif-method-excel) to count the occurrence of `a1` in the helper column as `rowCount`. So `rowEnd = rowStart + rowCount - 1`.

Now you can loop like …

```
Dim iRow As Long
For iRow = rowStart to rowEnd
    'use your dictionary and rowCount to replace values here.
    'Example for accessing the cell:
    Worksheets("MySheet").Cells(iRow, "E").Value = "" 
Next iRow
```

Comment: On checking the function definitions, I'm assuming I'd need to define a range for my entire helper column, as countIF would require a range to work upon so would find or can I use it on the column itself?

Comment: No need for a named range if the helper column is always in a specific column eg. column A then use something `Worksheet("MySheet").Range("A:A")` to reference the entire column A. Or `Worksheet("MySheet").Columns(1)` to reference the entire first column. Of course you can use these references with the functions `find` and `countif`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and I'm able to find the start and end row numbers. I'm unclear as to how how to iterate over the 'cells' in 'value' column for that row number as I could using ForEach in a named range.

Comment: I guess this might do ...
Cells(r, c).Value = x(r)

Comment: @hbabbar See my edited answer for an example. Always use a fully qualified worksheet with your `cells` or `range` like in my example to avoid any issues. You can use the column's letter `"E"` or  its number `5`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Would keep in mind the pointers you suggested. Just to improve upon the answer to take it to closure...
rowEnd = rowStart + rowCount - 1 (As the index of row would be one less)